# SQL: how to fetch a unique record according to a date (with NULL case included)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, record

Suppose we have these tables, referring a task to do for a single customer

```
AGENDAS
ID | DAY
86 | 2017-04-14
88 | 2017-04-22

WORKS
ID                   | IDAGENDA | TIME SLOT |  RESULT  | DATETIMEEXECUTED | IDORDER
IZ9`fiq|-=rRE7OKKO;P |    86    |  8-10 am  | canceled | 2017-04-13 10:45 | 10
g5wMkHa4Z?bQnFqDmXKn |    88    |  8-10 am  | canceled | 2017-04-19 16:30 | 10
n\mkLegfO>HSCJ/X:{ax |    88    |  13-15 pm |          |                  | 10
```

With the framework I (am forced to) use, when I create a panel I am allowed to write a single query in order for to fetch its data. This query is called master query. 
My boss wants a summary screen where, for each work order, I have to list the most recent agenda taken, and in case, the outcome of the task. So, let's suppose we have the situation of the tables above. In this case, I should list only the task with ID `n\mkLegfO>HSCJ/X:{ax` as it is the most recent inserted and reserved and still to be executed (the customer did not canceled it). 
But I don't know how to fetch this unique record because if, in the master query, I write:

```
select ...
from ORDERS O left join AGENDAS A on ...
     left join WORKS W1 on ...
where W1.IDORDER = 10 and W1.DATETIMEEXECUTED = (
   select max(W2.DATETIMEEXECUTED)
   from WORKS W2
   where W2.IDORDER = 10
)
```

then the record

```
g5wMkHa4Z?bQnFqDmXKn |    88    |  8-10 am  | canceled | 2017-04-19 16:30
```

would be returned which is not the most recent. On the other hand, if I try with:

```
select ...
from ORDERS O left join AGENDAS A on ...
     left join WORKS W1 on ...
where W1.IDORDER = 10 and (DATETIMEEXECUTED is null or  W1.DATETIMEEXECUTED = (
   select max(W2.DATETIMEEXECUTED)
   from WORKS W2
   where W2.IDORDER = 10)
```

then I get:

```
 g5wMkHa4Z?bQnFqDmXKn |    88    |  8-10 am  | canceled | 2017-04-19 16:30 | 10
 n\mkLegfO>HSCJ/X:{ax |    88    |  13-15 pm |          |                  | 10
```

which still is not correct. 
I think that the biggest problem is that I cannot perform a `max(ID)` aggregate function on `WORKS` table because as those records are created in mobile devices by field workers, the PK cannot be simply a integer counter and each device mobile as SQLite and each operator creates his own records before synchronize them with the central server. That's why our framework provides a PK as a `char(20)` pseudo-random characters.

As I'm an idiot, I did not think the date time of the creation of the work but this application is already in production so I wouldn't like to change the DB schema.
Moreover the `left join` is required because for that other, still no agenda and no appointment might still exist.

So, in the end: if there are only caneled works I would like to see the most recent one. On the contrary, if there is also one work still to do (with result and datetimeexecuted equal to null) I would like to get it.
Is there a solution?

Comment: it's sql server...as I had added

Comment: Are you looking for that lastest record for *one* IDORDER (e.g. IDORDER = 10) or for *multiple* IDORDER and their latest records?

Comment: What has the AGENDAS table to do with this?

Comment: I'm looking for the latest record for each IDORDER... the IDORDER=10 was just for example. Well, I know that AGENDAS tables maybe is superfluous. It was just to better explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest record for idorder = 10:

```
select top(1) *
from works
where idorder = 10 
  and coalesce(result, 'okay') <> 'canceled'
order by datetimeexecuted desc;
```

The latest record per idorder:

```
select *
from
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by idorder order by datetimeexecuted desc) as rn
  from works
  where coalesce(result, 'okay') <> 'canceled'
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

**Update:** The latest uncancelled record per idorder if any, otherwise the latest other record:

```
select *
from
(
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by idorder order by 
      case when result = 'canceled' then 2 else 1 end, datetimeexecuted desc) as rn
  from works
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Ehm, this query is supposed ti be run on the server so I cannot use coalesce

Comment: I don't understand this. `COALESCE` is standard SQL and available in SQL Server. Why would you be allowed to run a query, but only without `COALESCE`? This doesn't seem to make sense. (Anyway, `coalesce(result, 'okay') <> 'canceled'` can also be written as `result <> 'canceled' or result is null`.)

Comment: I'm sorry. I had seen `COALESCE()` only in SQLite while in SQL Server some other routines like `ISNULL()`. The same people who implemented the framework explained me that coalesce was reserved to SQLite. Sorry. Anyway, I'm afraid I'm not allowed insert a SELECT query as argument to FROM but only tables. I know that framework is limited...

Comment: Maybe I badly explained myself:  if there are only caneled works I would like to see the most recent one. On the contrary, if there is also one work still to do (with result and datetimeexecuted equal to null) I would like to get it. That's why I cannot simply use `result <> 'canceled' or result is null` because if there are only canceled works, then they would be excluded.

Comment: Then move the condition to row_number's order by clause, so as to get the uncancelled records before the cancelled ones. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ ThorstenKettner very kind of yours. I have to study about `row_number()` and `over partition by...` because I have never used them. Just one final question: unfortunately as I said I cannot use a SELECT query inside FROM in the master query of that framework but only tables or views. So, should I put `select *,  row_number() over (partition by idorder order by        case when result = 'canceled' then 2 else 1 end, datetimeexecuted desc) as rn   from works ) ranked` as a query of the view, would it work correctly anyway?

Comment: Without on-the-fly views (select inside `FROM` or using a cte) you are very limited and there are things you cannot do. The query I've shown needs them for instance. One way around this may be to create a real view (`CREATE VIEW ...`) for the inner query and then select from this. Another option would be a correlated `TOP` query in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Thorsten Kettner in his good answer, I created a new standard VIEW whose query is exactly the inner `SELECT *, row_number()...` and I used that VIEW in the master query of the panel instead of the classic table of `WORKS`.
In the end, to be more precise for my case, I had to perform the following:

```
select ...
from ORDERS O left join AGENDAS A on ...
              left join VIEW V on ...
where V.rn = 1 or (V.rn is null)
```

because if the work/appointment hasn't been still inserted at all, they want to see the other concerned data anyway.